# why eclipses crashes when i try to create a new android xml file

Tags: android

Every time when i try to create a new xml file ,or to open the androidanifest.xml, eclipse crashes . i can't find the solution of this problem . please i need some helpe

i'm using Eclipse SDK Version: 3.7.2 and android sdk r17 windows

after the crash of eclipse, a .log file is generated

---

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x4ebac1f6, pid=6136, tid=5600

JRE version: 6.0_31-b05
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.6-b01 mixed mode windows-x86 )
 Problematic frame:
 C  [gdiplus.dll+0x2c1f6]

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

......................

Comment: did it always do this? If it worked before and doesn't now I'd suggest re-installing Java and Eclipse. If it has never worked then I don't know, but trying the re-installs couldn't hurt.

Comment: which java version did you set in your eclipse ide?

Comment: As far as my experience goes, this happens when you install some EE plugins onto the same Eclipse as the Android plugin, and if to be more specific, this also happened to me after only installing the JavaScript plugin!

Answer (score 1):

Have you ensured your version of Eclipse is completely up to date (Help menu -> Check for Updates)??

Also as Tim mentioned, has this ever worked before? Or has it been an issue since install??

Comment: i re-install eclipse but i still have the same problem :((((